# Event logging / tracking in react-admin?

Tags: reactjs, google-analytics, react-admin, event-tracking, taplytics

We've built our admin app in `react-admin` and want to add event tracking to record user behaviour on the app (i.e. the pages they visit and the links they click) - is there an existing plugin to `react-admin` or lib that works well with `ra` that would do something like this?